# How to upgrade to React Native 0.57.0 version?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I create a project by CRNA and change to be a pure RN project.

When i type comman `react-native-git-upgrade` and run the project shows the error:

`error: bundling failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/motogod19/MyWork/test_upgrade/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/create-react-class/index.js'`

Before upgrade enviroment:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test_upgrade",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2"
  }
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/decorator-support"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-jsx-source"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

After upgrade:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test_upgrade",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {

    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.45.2",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "~0.57.0"
  }
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-jsx-source"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Step 1: If type `npm install create-react-class` and run it shows error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset" relative to directory "/Users/motogod19/MyWork/test_up"
    at /Users/motogod19/MyWork/test_up/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19
```

The option-manager.js line 293 is:

```
if (typeof val === "string") {
      presetLoc = (0, _resolvePreset2.default)(val, dirname);

      if (!presetLoc) {
        throw new Error("Couldn't find preset " + (0, _stringify2.default)(val) + " relative to directory " + (0, _stringify2.default)(dirname));
      }

      val = require(presetLoc);
    }
```

Still can't figure it out, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Run `react-native upgrade` and run the project.

If it's not working , install that module manually.

```
npm install create-react-class
```

Then somewhere in your code, add:

```
require('create-react-class');
```

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Yes ! I try `react-native upgrade` is working. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, Sorry my bad, it is not working untill i `npm install create-react-class` it shows another error `Couldn't find preset "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"`, i update it on my question. Can you check it again ? Thank you~

Comment: Did you install npm i metro-react-native-babel-preset --save-dev? Btw , is react-native upgrade not working?

Comment: No, I donot install  `npm i metro-react-native-babel-preset --save-dev` and  `eact-native upgrade` is not working.  So i try `npm i metro-react-native-babel-preset --save-dev` that shows error `Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source'`. What a nightmare, should i post the issue to https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app ?

Comment: Before that try to install that too. npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source

Comment: Hmm... I try `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source ` and next error is `error: bundling failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined. at PluginPass.JSXOpeningElement` So sad... :(

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
}
```

after you install module:metro-react-native-babel-preset, you need to put that in your .babelrc file instead of "react-native", they changed this, and are a lot of changes with babel 7, i just made the update, and on emulator it works, but when i install apk on the phone, it crashes immediatly, from what im reading its something with babel helpers... i try to figure out this.. no luck until now.. but for your question, that is the answer
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20150#issue-340235017